# Pegar dados textarea de um JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Sei que usar o `DefaultTableModel` não é a melhor maneira de se fazer as tabelas, porém eu ainda não dominei nada do `AbstractTableModel`, eu tenho uma tabela que é editada como JTextArea, porém quando eu digito não vem na variável de célula da table, gostaria de saber como eu pego o que foi digitado... o CellRenderer está fazendo o que eu quero, agora eu quero que ele pegue tudo que eu digito no `textarea` do `jTable`, segue o código:

```
public void preenche_evolucao(){ //Pega do banco de dados

        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) table_1.getModel();
    modelo.setNumRows(0);
    table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
    table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new CustomEditor());
    table_1.setRowHeight(50);
    try {

        Connection con = Conexao.getConexao();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, Data, Evolucao FROM tab2_perfil where IdPac='" + id + "'");

        while (RS.next()) {
            String dat = RS.getString("Data");
            String tab = RS.getString("Evolucao");
            String id = RS.getString("id");

            modelo.addRow(new Object[] { id, dat, tab });
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {

    }


public void salvaEv() throws java.lang.NullPointerException{ //Pega o que é escrito na célula para passar ao banco de dados

        int row = table_1.getSelectedRow();
    Object valor = table_1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
    Object valor2 = table_1.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();

    try {
        Connection con = Conexao.getConexao();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into tab2_perfil (idPac, Data, Evolucao) values ('" + id + "', '" + valor
                + "', '" + valor2 + "')");
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finalize a edição da tabela!");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

CustomEditor:

```
class CustomEditor implements TableCellEditor {
JTextArea textArea;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
public String text;

public CustomEditor() {
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
}

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    textArea.setText((String) value);
    return scrollPane;
}

public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
}

public void cancelCellEditing() {
}

public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return textArea.getText();
}

public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
    return true;
}

public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
}

public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
    return true;
}

public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    return true;
}
}
```

Custom Renderer:

```
class CustomRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
JScrollPane scrollPane;
JTextArea textArea;

public CustomRenderer() {
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    textArea.setText((String) value);
    return scrollPane;
}
}
```

Comment: Da uma formatada nesse código, fica dificil ler um codigo sem identacao, cheio de espaços vagos em branco.;

Comment: Pronto, dei um ctrl+shift+f kkkkkk ve se da pra entender alguma coisa agora, resumindo eu quero só pegar o que é digitado no textarea do jtable, que ta me retornando nulo...

Comment: Não está claro o problema. Pegar onde?

Comment: Da para postar print aqui?, ficaria bem claro... Vou explicar melhor, tenho a DefaultTableModel, nela tem os campos id, data e evolução, id e data estão padrão, mas a evolução precisa ser em formato de textarea, o CellEditor faz isso para mim, porém eu não consigo pegar as informações que eu escrevo dentro da evolução

Comment: Não consegue pegar onde? Seu celleditor está bem estranho, veja um exemplo simples de um celleditor, use-o como referencia. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CreatingaCustomTableCellEditorinaJTableComponent.htm

Comment: Não consegue pegar os valores da coluna evolução

Comment: Com esse editor aí vc consegue salvar o que você digita no textarea??

Comment: Ah, testei aqui a sua referencia, segunda feira adapto para meu código, obrigado amigo

Comment: O que eu precisava era só pegar os dados do textArea, mas o CellEditor estava errado, não consegui, mas com o seu exemplo simplificado no meu teste funcionou bem, agr é só adaptar para o meu código

Comment: Como eu coloco uma barra de rolagem?